# Understanding why using weak deallocates stored properties after being instantiated inside a function

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting, xctest

Even after reading Swift's documentation about ARC, I'm still having trouble understanding why a property was set to nil even when it's instantiated within a function.  I have the following sample code:

```
import UIKit

class ItemListViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView = UITableView()

    }


}
```

And here is the sample code for the test run:

```
import XCTest
@testable import PassionProject

class ItemListViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }
    func tests_TableViewIsNotNil_AfterViewDidLoad(){

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController")
        let sut = viewController as! ItemListViewController
        _ = sut.view
        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.tableView)
    }

    func tests_loadingView_SetsUITableViewDataSource(){

    }

}
```

Inside the function that is being tested, we've created the correct instances and I understand that calling the view property fires the viewDidLoad() method.  I'm not sure why the test states that the tableView property is nil when running the test.  I'd like to understand ARC from this perspective and realize what is happening under the hood when the test states that the tableView property is nil.  We've clearly instantiated the UITableView object inside viewDidLoad().  I understand that this test passes when removing "weak" from the tableView property but I don't understand why.  Any explanation would be greatly appreciated to understand this better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm still having trouble understanding why a property was set to nil even when it's instantiated within a function
>
> ```
> @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
>
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
>     tableView = UITableView()
> }
> ```

Then you haven't understood what `weak` means. It means: *this* reference has no ability to keep this object alive. Thus, if nothing else keeps this object alive (i.e. retains it), the object will die no matter *how* it is instantiated.

Your code creates the table view: `UITableView()`. It assigns the table view to a variable: `tableView = UITableView()`. But that variable is *weak*. It has no power to keep this table view alive. And you didn't do anything *else* that would keep this table view alive. Therefore the table view *instantly dies*, vanishing in a puff of smoke, and leaving `tableView` pointing at nothing — and so `tableView` is reset to `nil`.

The usual thing, however, is to talk like this:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
let tv = UITableView(frame:someRect)
self.view.addSubview(tv)
tableView = tv
```

That makes all the difference in the world. The `tableView` variable is still weak, and still can't keep the table view alive. But we added the table view as a subview to `self.view`, and now its *superview keeps it alive*.

And that is the reason why outlets are often weak. It's because they refer to views that have superviews that already keep them alive, so there is no need for a *second* reference (the outlet property) to keep them alive as well.

Comment: This is appreciated and definitely makes sense.  You don't have to go into detail because its a different question but can you tell me when it would be a good idea to use weak?

Comment: When failure to do so would cause a retain cycle: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_memory_management

Comment: Note that the local variable `tv` also maintains a reference to `tableView` which is what keeps it alive long enough for you to add it as a subview to self.view.  The local variable of course stops retaining `tableView` at the end of the function.

Comment: thx @matt for explaining the **outlet weak** for me, another question is that why there are 2 kinds of @ IBOutlet (strong and weak) ,when you connect the view to code?

Comment: @SaiLi Well, they want to give you a choice. Let's say you plan to remove this view from the interface later, and then put it back into the interface even later. You'll want a strong reference, because otherwise when you remove it from its superview it will vanish. But usually you _don't_ intend to do that, and a weak reference will do, because the superview will keep a strong reference and you don't need another one. Does that make sense?